# Get object from another method

Tags: c#, object, methods

I cant get value from another method
Need to show at RTB the values from the object alunoTrabalhadorEstudantes
Not so good at english sorry. and new in programming

```cs
public string getNomes
{
    get { return nome; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Mostrar(object umObjecto)
    {
        richTextBox.AppendText(umObjecto + "\n");
    }
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aluno alunoTrabalhadorEstudante = new aluno("Teodoro Silva");
    }
    public void Executar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //My erro is here, cant access the object
        Mostrar(alunoTrabalhadorEstudante.getNomes);
    }
}
```

Comment: `aluno alunoTrabalhadorEstudante` is in the function scope. You'd need a class variable for it to be accessable. You should follow a c# beginners guide where you learn about methods, classes, fields, .. :) [This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: How i get my class variable @Joelius

Comment: Put it (`aluno alunoTrabalhadorEstudante`) directly inside the class declaration, not inside a method. You can still assign it in a method (`alunoTrabalhadorEstudante = ...`). You should read about [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Also read about [naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions), classes should always be PascalCase.

Comment: Works, thanks @Joelius